# Simple Windows example of automating a .exe program using subprocess and .Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin, stderr

I am new to the subprocess module, and after reading the [Python documents](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) among many other websites (including Stack Overflow), I am struggling to find simplified examples of `.Popen`, `.communicate`, and other such useful classes. Often, the examples never use each class in succession, only on their own. Also, many examples are Linux-based, such as the use of `["ls", "-l"]`, which makes it quite difficult to understand for Windows users.

After several hours playing with this module, I have encountered several issues, which could be best illustrated through the method of opening and communicating with a simple .exe command line program.

For example, say that the program is called "numbers.exe", and that it asks the following questions:

```
>>> Question 1) Choose 1, 2 or 3
>>> Question 2) Choose 4, 5 or 6
>>> You have answered #(Q1) and #(Q2)
>>> *Use these values in an iterative sequence displaying each stage in the iteration*
```

I then want to manipulate this program automatically, i.e. I want python to input 2 and 6 without me having to do anything, but still print the questions. I then want to be able to view the iteration in python.

The first consideration here is that I could use:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

numprog = subprocess.call('numbers.exe')
print(numprog.communicate())
```

However, this just opens the program, and I would still have to enter 2 and 6 myself. To automate the process, I believe I must use `Popen`, alongside stdin, stdout and stderr. This is where I encounter issues. I understand I must use Popen to begin communicating with the input (stdin), output (stdout) and error (stderr) pipes:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

numcomms = Popen('numbers.exe', stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

I am unsure what to do from here. Using `numcomms.stdout.read()` causes the program to just linger, and using `numcomms.stdin.write(2)` throws out an error that int values cannot be used. The `numprog.communicate` class seems to require you to enter the values yourself.

From what I can see, the pseudo code would be along the lines:

```
>>> Open numbers.exe stdin, stdout and stderr pipes using Popen
>>> Print first question using stdout
>>> Enter "2" using stdin
>>> Print second question using stdout
>>> Enter "6" using stdin
>>> Receive a string saying "You have answered 2 and 6" using stdout
>>> Display the results of each stage of the iteration using stdout
```

How would I go about writing this?

Really appreciate the help, thank you!

**Edit**: Edited the question to describe the iterative sequence issue. Michael has suggested a good resolution to the inputting issue, however I am having trouble printing the results of the iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `subprocess.stdin.write` is probably that you need to provide a string instead of an integer, as Steve Barnes pointed out correcly.

However, for your simple case their might be an easier solution. The `communicate` method has an optional parameter for input, so this should work:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

numcomms = Popen('numbers.exe', stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = numcomms.communicate("2\n6\n")
```

The output of the program should be in `out` afterwards, and can easily be splitted using `out.splitlines()`.

Comment: I attempted using a string for the write function; that didn't work either. Unfortunately, I get the same error if I use the out, err = numcomms.communicate("2\n6\n") solution. The error states "'str' does not support the buffer interface".
Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Are you using Python 3.x? In that case you need the encode the string. Try using `numcomms.communicate("2\n6\n".encode())` in that case.

Comment: Thank you, that no longer throws up an error; however I now have an issue with printing!
Entirely my fault; I forgot to mention that the .exe program uses these numbers in an iterative cycle, and displays each stage in the cycle indefinitely. When I use the code you suggested, the cursor just lingers on screen and doesn't print anything, which would suggest that the iteration is working, but the python code isn't printing the results. Would you have any suggestions for this?

Really appreciate your patience!

Comment: +1 - nice example, how to interact with the command prompt/terminal

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem with the subprocess.stdin.write is that the program will be expecting a string probably terminated with a newline i.e. '2\n' rather than an int.